# Users cannot update iOS app, after iTunes app transfer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes

I recently transferred my app from one iTunes Connect account to another. After that I released new version of the app, but users cannot update to it. There is no update button next to app on AppStore, instead there is cloud with down arrow. When pressed that cloud button app will download but at the end alert will popup with "Can not download right now" text, and app will revert to the previous version.
What can I do to fix this??
This is very critical issue.

Comment: Best solution will be contacting Apple for technical support.

Comment: I did it, but there was no response for more than 4 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 or 6 hours it just fixed, and everything worked like it should.